# How to create vacuum rocket engine plume

Tags: animation, texturing, shader-nodes, emission

I would need to create an animation of a rocket engine in a vacuum. It doesn't look like what most people imagine exhaust from a rocket engine to look like. It's like a "quick, slightly luminous fog". Here are some examples of what I would like it to look like:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how to do this? I did a few tutorials on atmospheric rocket engine exhaust and it didn't help me much, I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try it with a procedural material:

[image]

Create a cylinder, subdivide horizontally, deform, unwrap with the *Cylinder Projection* option:

[image]

Give it a material that is a mix between *Emission* and *Transparency*, that is stretched on Y (as it is using the *UV* output of the *Texture Coordinate*), create a transparent gradient on Z, also make the periphery more blurry with the help of an *Input > Layer Weight*:

[image]

You could put a second cylinder inside the first one to create more gaz, emit a bit of particles, etc...

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't quite make it. I didn't know how to unwarp, but I kept going. I managed to create a cone that is luminous at the top and not at the bottom, but the transition between luminosity and non-luminosity is very sharp. I also didn't quite make the longitudinal dark stripes. I also don't have the location X, Y and Z boxes in the mapping node green (I know it's some really stupid problem, but I can't figure out what's causing it). And then when I start the animation, it doesn't move. Anyway, what you created looks really great.