# How to blow fog in one direction? (rocket engine ignition)

Tags: animation, shader-nodes, volumetrics, emission

(sorry for the unclear title, I had no idea what to call it)
I'm making an animation of a rocket engine ignition in a vacuum. I would like to do the same as in this video:
https://youtu.be/xMr_AGJprrg
The "fog" I'm asking about starts specifically at 0:16.

I'm pretty good at making an exhaust from a rocket engine that's already running. The procedure I use is described in this question:
[How to create vacuum rocket engine plume](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/290145/how-to-create-vacuum-rocket-engine-plume)
[image]

I thought I would use the same process for the fog, but it looks wrong. The problem is that the fire only needs to be around the perimeter, while the fog has to be in the entire volume. I would like to achieve that "messy" effect at 0:18. Here is my attempt:
[image]

The engine model I am using is this: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3566663